# Pass any number of arguments to a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-query

I have a shared function that accepts a callback, which in turn accepts any number and type of arguments. How can I make it, so TS just accepts anything as the callback's argument?

the callback can be `(true, 'test', 1) => {...}`, as well as `({a:'foo', b:true}) => {...}`, or `() => {...}`

My first try way:

`type F = (args?: any) => Promise<...>`

But this accepts one argument. I thought about:

`...args: any[]`, but this requires an array.

Typing the callback as `any` is my last resort, but it's not the proper solution here.

Comment: _"but this requires an array"_ - no, it doesn't. It requires `...args`, i.e. the array of all arguments, to be an array. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters-and-arguments.

Comment: `...args` is right answer, thats only way to get any no. of args. for type, you can either use `...args: any[]` or `...args: unknown[]`

Comment: What's with the `T` and `Promise<T>`? Your question doesn't mention that at all; if it's irrelevant, could you remove it from the example? Could you also provide a [mre] of how you intend to use this? Saying "the function accepts a callback that accepts any number and type of arguments" is somewhat ambiguous. It *could* mean "the function accepts any callback, no matter what number and type of arguments it accepts" or it *could* mean "the function accepts only a callback that itself don't care about the number and type of arguments it receives". An appropriate code example would clear that up.

Comment: That one "the function accepts only a callback that itself don't care about the number and type of arguments it receives". But `...args: any[]` does work after all. Not sure why I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine;
`const myFunc = (...args: any) => {}`